# Using SVG files in android and memory usage

Tags: android, memory, svg

My application has an activity with metro schema, so for good quality I need to put image with resolution more then 2000x2000, but such images use much memory and application crashes with Out of memory error.
Does this problem will solve when I will change the image source to SVG (by svg-android for example)?

Comment: It would help if we could see some code, and a stack trace from the error. I'm assuming you'd be unpacking this SVG into a single bitmap of some kind for display? If so, the size of the file won't matter at all, only the size of the final bitmap. (Also, in that case, even if the memory wasn't a problem, you'll hit issues on some devices if you go above 2048 pixels on any edge if you're using hardware acceleration, as that's the safe texture size limit for the underlying OpenGL textures that get used...)

Comment: Metro style... do you mean BIG COLOR SQUARES? If so, why using images (svgs will be transformed to bitmaps after all)? Just make a  GridView with each cell having a different background color...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the complexity of image simple vector re presentable image will defiantly improve the performance otherwise complex images will use more memory.

more Details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_intro.asp).